# concat string within ffmpeg subprocess check_call

Tags: python, ffmpeg

need to replace filename in subprocess command i.e. filename

```
filename = '\'D\:/imagesequence/thumbnail.jpg\''


task = '\"movie= ' + filename + '[watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/3 [out]\"'
```

c = subprocess.check_call(["ffmpeg", "-i", "D:/imagesequence/background222.jpg", "-vf", task, "D:/imagesequence/fwtm108.jpg"],shell=True)

this gives error

```
# Error: CalledProcessError: Command '['ffmpeg', '-i', 'D:/imagesequence/background222.jpg', '-vf', '"movie= \'D\\:/imagesequence/thumbnail.jpg\'[watermark];[in][watermark] overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/3 [out]"', 'D:/imagesequence/fwtm107.jpg']' returned non-zero exit status 1 #
```

when put altogether it works well

```
c = subprocess.check_call(["ffmpeg", "-i", "D:/imagesequence/background222.jpg", "-vf", "movie= 'D\:/imagesequence/thumbnail.jpg'[watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/3 [out]", "D:/imagesequence/fwtm101.jpg"],shell=True)
```

even this works

```
task = "movie= 'D\:/imagesequence/thumbnail.jpg'[watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/3 [out]"

c = subprocess.check_call(["ffmpeg", "-i", "D:/imagesequence/background222.jpg", "-vf", task, "D:/imagesequence/fwtm102.jpg"],shell=True)
```

any different view. I am not able to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
q = "D\:/imagesequence/thumbnail.jpg"
task = "movie= '%s'[watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/3 [out]" % q

c = subprocess.check_call(["ffmpeg", "-i", "D:/imagesequence/background222.jpg", "-vf", task, "D:/imagesequence/fwtm106.jpg"],shell=True)
```

this worked. thank you to

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.tutor/65858